# SAS programming, read from a file and separate into different column

Tags: sas

I have a excel-file where I want to split words into different columns in SAS. 
In the file it looks like this in the same column, I want to split it and get rid of quotation marks :

```
ID;"City";"Year"
1;"New york";NULL
2;"stockton";"18"
```

**This is what I tried to do:**

```
data work.project ;                     
infile "&path\users.csv" delimiter=';' missover dsd;
input ID: $30.
      City: $200.
      Year: $5. ;

run;

proc print data=work.project;
run;
```

**My output:**

Obs   ID   City      Year

1 ,,,"ID ""City"" ""Year
2 ,,,"1 ""new york"" NULL"
3 ,,,"2 ""stockton"" ""18"
4 ,,,"3 ""moscow "" NULL"

Comment: Your question title says Excel, but the code in the question reads a .csv.  Which is it?  Please show the output you are getting from your sample code, and describe how it is wrong.  The code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is a .csv file! I have add the output in my question now. I want to get rid of the quotations... I tried to use for example $quote200., but then I lost the values

Comment: I would double check your file. Or paste your sample file from this question into a new csv, and run your code from this question. I don’t get quote marks or the extra commas in my SAS dataset. Running on windows.

Comment: CSV files are NOT Excel files. Open the file with NOTEPAD or other text editor to see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the colon and formats in the `INPUT` statement use an `INFORMAT` statement.

```
data work.project;
    infile datalines4 delimiter=';' truncover dsd;
    informat id $30. city $200. year $4.;
    input ID City Year;
    datalines4;
1;"New York";NULL
2;"Stockton";"18"
;;;;
run;

proc print data=project;
run;
```

Comment: SAS does not need use an INFORMAT to read character variables.  If you want to define the variables use a LENGTH statement.